# error occurred configuring project react-native-photo-view

Tags: android, react-native, shoutem

I have just started with ReactNative and created a project using [this tutorial](http://array151.com/blog/react-native-setup-android-environment-windows/). The project got built and a android application got installed on my phone.

Then I used `@shoutem/ui` library for UI components. According to the [documentation](https://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/introduction), I tried

```
npm install @shoutem/ui --save
react-native link
```

and then run the project using

```
react-native run-android
```

But then I got this error

```
PS D:\SK\Study\ReactNative\DemoRN> react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in D:\SK\Study\ReactNative\DemoRN\node_modules (38ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
File C:\Users\sukumar\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Failed to download any source lists!
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-photo-view'.
      > Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.028 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

And then I unlinked the `@shoutem/ui`

```
react-native unlink @shoutem/ui
```

and tried to run the project, but still, I am facing the same issue?

Please ignore if it is too basic to ask, But I am not able to understand what is the issue?

**Update**

I am not using Android Studio, So I downloaded the `build-tools 25.0.0` and placed in sdk/build-tools folder. But now I am facing

```
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-photo-view'. > Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using Android Studio, So I downloaded the **build-tools 25.0.0** and placed in SDK/build-tools folder. This solved the build tools issue but then there was a new issue

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-photo-view'. > Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-23
```

The network I was using has configured some firewalls rules that were not allowing the required dependencies get downloaded. When you run `react-native run-android` it downloads all the dependencies automatically to create the build.

So In my case, I changed my network settings and this worked.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with the available SDK Tools in your installation of Android Studio:

```
      > Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.0
```

Installing these should resolve the issue. To install this, start up Android studio, go to the SDK Manager and select the SDK Tools tab, check the `Show Package Details` option in the bottom right corner and then check the 25.0.0 SDK Tools and click Apply to download and install them.

Here's a screenshot of the SDK Tools I use for my local environment for reference:

[image]

Furthermore, I'd just like to elaborate on the `react-native (un)link` command. This is used to link native dependencies into your React Native project. Unlinking it is not the same as uninstalling it, you should still be able to use all non-native components of the Shoutem UI Toolkit after unlinking the package.

Comment: I am not using Android Studio, So i downloaded the `build-tools 25.0.0` and placed in sdk/build-tools folder. But now I am facing `> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-photo-view'.
      > Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-23`